# Add manual steps to deployment plan in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

Is there a way to add a task as a manual step in a deployment plan? Like some sort of manual intervention where if the user confirms it will go to the next step, if they deny it doesn't.

Comment: Hi Dave, have you found a solution? I also need to add a manual step in my deployment project.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a Deployment ***Project*** - which is different from a normal Bamboo build plan that happens to do a deployment - the answer is no.  Deployment Projects in Bamboo aren't normal build plans. They don't have stages or jobs that you can add/edit/remove - they only have tasks.  In Bamboo, Stages and Plans are the build concepts you can designate as manual.  Since deployment projects have no stages, you lose the ability to have a manual intervention inside a deployment project.

This is one reason some folks just use normal Bamboo build plans for deployment rather than Deployment Projects.  It's an unfortunate omission in their capabilities.

If the reason you want this feature is to have a manual step between deployments to two different environments, there is a way.  If you really want to do something in the middle of a deployment, and have manual confirmation (like remind someone to cut-over routers and verify they've done it), there's not a way I know of to do that with a Deployment Project.  You'd need to do your deployment with just a vanilla Bamboo build plan.

Comment: Bummer, I wanted to have a few different. Like for QA to be able to validate a build, or run a suite of integration tests in a particular environment etc. The whole deployment plan capabilities seem lackluster. Maybe need to look into configuration as code.

Comment: QA validation of a build sounds like something that might happen between deployments, rather than in the middle of a deployment, and that can done with deployment projects - in fact they have a built in feature for marking a deployment verified.  A manual step in the middle of deploying to an environment is what is problematic.

Comment: @DaveN Build plans (not deployment projects) can have multiple sequential stages, and a stage can be a manual stage so if you have parts A, B, and C you need to do, where B is a manual step, you'd have three stages.  Stage A, Stage B (manual), and Stage C.